# Null is not an object while creating navigation between screens in expo project

Tags: react-native, navigation

I need to open new screen after clicking on the button. For it I made the following steps:

1) Installed [this](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) library

2) Created a new screen and added it to the folder with other screens (DetailInfoScreen is a new screen, which should be opened and HomeScreen is a screen, where a button, after clicking on which new screen should be opened):

[image]

3) Added the following lines of code:

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import DetailInfoScreen from './DetailInfoScreen';
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onPressSearch = this.onPressSearch.bind(this);
    Navigation.registerComponent('DetailInfoScreen', () => DetailInfoScreen);
  }
goToScreen = (screenName) => {
    Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
      component: {
        name: screenName
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { list, text } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.searchContainer}>

          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this.goToScreen('DetailInfoScreen')}
          >

            <View>

              <Text>Search</Text>

            </View>

          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
);
}
```

But when I run the project I have the following error:

[image]

And one more moment which disturbs me is that autocorrection in vscode doesn't see my new screen while importing:

[image]

Maybe it doesn't play any role, but still. So, what's the reason of the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply navigate to another screen by using this:

```js
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailInfoScreen')>
  <Text>Search</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally advice for you to use react-navigation instead of react-native-navigation, you can read more on this [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html)